# PowerPivot doesn't install in SharePoint mode on an Active/Passive Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, high-availability

We a provisioning a new SQL Failover Cluster. We have successfully configured the SQL instance, and have moved on to configuration of the PowerPivot for SharePoint instance. We run the configuration wizard, and create a new failover cluster. However when the install completes, the resultant Analysis Services instance is in Multidimensional Mode (Compatibility level 1100) rather than in SharePoint integrated mode.

After the configuration had completed, the SSAS instance is in the wrong mode.

This works fine on a non-clustered instance in a VM lab, anyone else experienced a similar issue and hopefully has a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just got off the phone with Microsoft about this very same question this morning.  According to MS, there is an internal document from the product team stating that this is an unsupported scenario.  Which really stinks because we wanted to leverage our existing cluster licensing for SSAS rather than paying for an additional stand alone instance.  At any rate, hope this helps.  I have requested additional guidance if this is going to be tested and supported in a future CU or SP or if MS is going to remove the capability of allowing someone to install a clustered instance of SSAS in SharePoint Mode through the installer.

Comment: Catching up after the weekend :) We also raised a case and have had the same answer - it's unsupported and doesn't work. The guidance I have from MS is now the following:

Install SSAS on both servers. 
Install the SQL DB cluster in active/passive
Pay for two licences

Trying in a VM lab now to see if this will actually work...